# Creating JSON header on php for android

Tags: php, android, json, header

I am going to create an android application for receiving data from database. I tested my app which can only receive a particular JSON format. I try to add this JSON header in the php document,

> header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');

however, it is useless.

this is my JSON printed by php:

```
[
"{\"user\":\"\",\"password\":\"\"}",
"{\"user\":\"\",\"password\":\"\"}",
"{\"user\":\"\",\"password\":\"\"}",
"{\"user\":\"\",\"password\":\"\"}",
"{\"user\":\"\",\"password\":\"\"}",
"{\"user\":\"\",\"password\":\"\"}",
"{\"user\":\"\",\"password\":\"\"}",
"{\"user\":\"\",\"password\":\"\"}",
"{\"user\":\"\",\"password\":\"\"}",
"{\"user\":\"\",\"password\":\"\"}",
"{\"user\":\"\",\"password\":\"\"}",
"{\"user\":\"\",\"password\":\"\"}",
"{\"user\":\"s\",\"password\":\"s\"}",
"{\"user\":\"hi\",\"password\":\"tom\"}",
"{\"user\":\"vhj\",\"password\":\"fgg\"}",
"{\"user\":\"d\",\"password\":\"h\"}",
"{\"user\":\"dh\",\"password\":\"hl\"}",
"{\"user\":\"p\",\"password\":\"p\"}",
"{\"user\":\"pon\",\"password\":\"pon\"}",
"{\"user\":\"\",\"password\":\"\"}",
"{\"user\":\"\",\"password\":\"\"}",
"{\"user\":\"\",\"password\":\"\"}",
"{\"user\":\"\",\"password\":\"\"}",
"{\"user\":\"\",\"password\":\"\"}",
"{\"user\":\"s\",\"password\":\"s\"}",
"{\"user\":\"\",\"password\":\"\"}",
"{\"user\":\"\",\"password\":\"\"}",
"{\"user\":\"\",\"password\":\"\"}",
"{\"user\":\"\",\"password\":\"\"}",
"{\"user\":\"\",\"password\":\"\"}"
]
```

and i want to change it format to this

```
{
"goodstart":[
{
    "user": "A",
    "password": "123"
}
]
}
```

seek help!!!

php code

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$con=mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASSWORD);

$dbconnect=mysqli_select_db($con, DB) or die ('Select Error:'.mysql_error());

$sql_query="SELECT * FROM `goodstart`"; 

$result=mysqli_query($con, $sql_query);

$output=array();

while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    $output[]= json_encode($row);
}
    print json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Show PHP code where creating JSONObject

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you asking how to write the JSON or you are having a particular problem?

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. I am asking how to write the JSON for android apps. I know Android can only receive the standard JSON format? / style?. However, the one I printed from php cannot be recognized by Android. Therefore, i want to modify php document in order to print a JSON which can be recognized my Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    echo "{\n";
    echo '"goodstart":';
    print str_replace('",', "\",\n",str_replace('}",', "\n},",str_replace('"{', "{\n",str_replace('\"', '"',json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)))));
    echo "\n}";
```

solved